# I want to print only the repeated values once from an associative array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, object

I have an associative array and want to print all the department but the Department should not be repeated

```
<h3>2. List out all department  name </h3>
<div class="all">
</div>
```

And My Jquery code is

```
var employee=[{"firstName":"Zahir","lastName":"Alam","Age":25,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"Developer","Department":"Tech","Head":{"Id":3,"Name":"Sourasis Roy"}},{"firstName":"Amith","lastName":"Manniken","Age":25,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"Developer","Department":"Tech","Head":{"Id":3,"Name":"Sourasis Roy"}},{"firstName":"Sourasis","lastName":"Roy","Age":28,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"CTO"},{"firstName":"Aditya","lastName":"Mishra","Age":29,"Company":"Switchme","Department":"Tech","Role":"CEO"},{"firstName":"Priti","lastName":"Lata","Age":24,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"HR"},{"firstName":"Sumita","lastName":"Nath","Age":24,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"HLA Head","Department":"Crm"},{"firstName":"Tarini","lastName":"Khanna","Age":22,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"Content Writer"},{"firstName":"Abhisek","lastName":"Soni","Age":23,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"HLA","Department":"Crm","Head":{"Id":5,"Name":"Sumita Nath"}},{"firstName":"Ankit","lastName":"Pump","Age":23,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"HLA","Department":"Crm","Head":{"Id":5,"Name":"Sumita Nath"}},{"firstName":"Pogo","lastName":"Laal","Age":23,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"Designer"},{"firstName":"Sabina","lastName":"Sekh","Age":28,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"HLA Head","Department":"Crm"},{"firstName":"Sanjay","lastName":"Poudal","Age":24,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"HLA Head","Department":"Crm","Head":{"Id":10,"Name":"Sabina Sekh"}}];

function unique(employee) {
    var result = [];
    $.each(list, function(i, e) {
        if ($.inArray(e, result) == -1) result.push(e);
    });
    return  $("div.all").text("result");
}
```

Tech,Crm
should be the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `filter` and `map`, with a `Set` to remove the repeated values:

```js
var employee=[{"firstName":"Zahir","lastName":"Alam","Age":25,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"Developer","Department":"Tech","Head":{"Id":3,"Name":"Sourasis Roy"}},{"firstName":"Amith","lastName":"Manniken","Age":25,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"Developer","Department":"Tech","Head":{"Id":3,"Name":"Sourasis Roy"}},{"firstName":"Sourasis","lastName":"Roy","Age":28,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"CTO"},{"firstName":"Aditya","lastName":"Mishra","Age":29,"Company":"Switchme","Department":"Tech","Role":"CEO"},{"firstName":"Priti","lastName":"Lata","Age":24,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"HR"},{"firstName":"Sumita","lastName":"Nath","Age":24,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"HLA Head","Department":"Crm"},{"firstName":"Tarini","lastName":"Khanna","Age":22,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"Content Writer"},{"firstName":"Abhisek","lastName":"Soni","Age":23,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"HLA","Department":"Crm","Head":{"Id":5,"Name":"Sumita Nath"}},{"firstName":"Ankit","lastName":"Pump","Age":23,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"HLA","Department":"Crm","Head":{"Id":5,"Name":"Sumita Nath"}},{"firstName":"Pogo","lastName":"Laal","Age":23,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"Designer"},{"firstName":"Sabina","lastName":"Sekh","Age":28,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"HLA Head","Department":"Crm"},{"firstName":"Sanjay","lastName":"Poudal","Age":24,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"HLA Head","Department":"Crm","Head":{"Id":10,"Name":"Sabina Sekh"}}];
var repeated = [...new Set(employee.map(({ Department }) => Department).filter(Boolean))];
$("div.all").text(repeated.join(", "));
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<h3>2. List out all department name </h3>
<div class="all"></div>
```

Comment: if i have to print it in a div tag how should i do?

Comment: OK @stuart, I'll put that in my answer.

Comment: @stuart I have edited my answer, does it work for you now?

Comment: No problem @stuart, always glad to help. If my answer fixed your problem, consider marking it as accepted by clicking the grey tick mark to the left of my answer.

Comment: What will be the problem?

Comment: @stuart Which browser are you using? Arrow functions aren't supported in older browsers.

Comment: I have latest version of Mozilla Firefox

Answer (score 0):

You can `map` the array to get the `Department`, use `Set` to get unique values. And use `filter` to remove undefined

```js
var employee=[{"firstName":"Zahir","lastName":"Alam","Age":25,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"Developer","Department":"Tech","Head":{"Id":3,"Name":"Sourasis Roy"}},{"firstName":"Amith","lastName":"Manniken","Age":25,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"Developer","Department":"Tech","Head":{"Id":3,"Name":"Sourasis Roy"}},{"firstName":"Sourasis","lastName":"Roy","Age":28,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"CTO"},{"firstName":"Aditya","lastName":"Mishra","Age":29,"Company":"Switchme","Department":"Tech","Role":"CEO"},{"firstName":"Priti","lastName":"Lata","Age":24,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"HR"},{"firstName":"Sumita","lastName":"Nath","Age":24,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"HLA Head","Department":"Crm"},{"firstName":"Tarini","lastName":"Khanna","Age":22,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"Content Writer"},{"firstName":"Abhisek","lastName":"Soni","Age":23,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"HLA","Department":"Crm","Head":{"Id":5,"Name":"Sumita Nath"}},{"firstName":"Ankit","lastName":"Pump","Age":23,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"HLA","Department":"Crm","Head":{"Id":5,"Name":"Sumita Nath"}},{"firstName":"Pogo","lastName":"Laal","Age":23,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"Designer"},{"firstName":"Sabina","lastName":"Sekh","Age":28,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"HLA Head","Department":"Crm"},{"firstName":"Sanjay","lastName":"Poudal","Age":24,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"HLA Head","Department":"Crm","Head":{"Id":10,"Name":"Sabina Sekh"}}];

var result = [...new Set(employee.map(o => o.Department))].filter(o => o);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This prints the unique values on the console. What are you expecting?

Comment: What will be my errors according to you?I am expecting the same but my browser is not showing anything