# I want to loop through associative array where age>23 and <27

Tags: jquery

I am looping with an If condition but it is showing me only the first result,I have to get the first and last name of all the employees in the associative array where condition is 23>age<27

```
     var employee=[{"firstName":"Zahir","lastName":"Alam","Age":25,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"Developer","Department":"Tech","Head":{"Id":3,"Name":"Sourasis Roy"}},{"firstName":"Amith","lastName":"Manniken","Age":25,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"Developer","Department":"Tech","Head":{"Id":3,"Name":"Sourasis Roy"}},{"firstName":"Sourasis","lastName":"Roy","Age":28,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"CTO"},{"firstName":"Aditya","lastName":"Mishra","Age":29,"Company":"Switchme","Department":"Tech","Role":"CEO"},{"firstName":"Priti","lastName":"Lata","Age":24,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"HR"},{"firstName":"Sumita","lastName":"Nath","Age":24,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"HLA Head","Department":"Crm"},{"firstName":"Tarini","lastName":"Khanna","Age":22,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"Content Writer"},{"firstName":"Abhisek","lastName":"Soni","Age":23,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"HLA","Department":"Crm","Head":{"Id":5,"Name":"Sumita Nath"}},{"firstName":"Ankit","lastName":"Pump","Age":23,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"HLA","Department":"Crm","Head":{"Id":5,"Name":"Sumita Nath"}},{"firstName":"Pogo","lastName":"Laal","Age":23,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"Designer"},{"firstName":"Sabina","lastName":"Sekh","Age":28,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"HLA Head","Department":"Crm"},{"firstName":"Sanjay","lastName":"Poudal","Age":24,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"HLA Head","Department":"Crm","Head":{"Id":10,"Name":"Sabina Sekh"}}];
    $.each( employee, function( key, value ) {
            if(value["Age"] >23 || value["Age"] <27) {
                $("div.age").text(""+ (value["firstName"])+" "+(value["lastName"]));
                $("div.age").join(",");
            }
        });
     <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <h3>4. List out all employee whose age&gt;23 and age&lt;27 ( comma separated)</h3>  
<div class="age"></div>
```

All the first and last name

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have "associative arrays." What you have there is an array of objects.

Comment: [Your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55771879/i-want-to-print-only-the-repeated-values-once-from-an-associative-array) has an answer that, amongst other things, loops through this structure. What's the question here, then?

Comment: Can you guide me with the output Please, my condition is not looping for every element

Comment: The array is not looping it is not providing me with exact output

Comment: the loop works, just say you are not getting the correct output.

Comment: Is this posted code correct?

Comment: Yes I am not getting the correct output @JuniusL.

Comment: The output I am getting is Just Zahir Alam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to do so much with DOM, why don't you just generate your required output and put it in the DOM? Like

```js
const employee =[{"firstName":"Zahir","lastName":"Alam","Age":25,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"Developer","Department":"Tech","Head":{"Id":3,"Name":"Sourasis Roy"}},{"firstName":"Amith","lastName":"Manniken","Age":25,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"Developer","Department":"Tech","Head":{"Id":3,"Name":"Sourasis Roy"}},{"firstName":"Sourasis","lastName":"Roy","Age":28,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"CTO"},{"firstName":"Aditya","lastName":"Mishra","Age":29,"Company":"Switchme","Department":"Tech","Role":"CEO"},{"firstName":"Priti","lastName":"Lata","Age":24,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"HR"},{"firstName":"Sumita","lastName":"Nath","Age":24,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"HLA Head","Department":"Crm"},{"firstName":"Tarini","lastName":"Khanna","Age":22,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"Content Writer"},{"firstName":"Abhisek","lastName":"Soni","Age":23,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"HLA","Department":"Crm","Head":{"Id":5,"Name":"Sumita Nath"}},{"firstName":"Ankit","lastName":"Pump","Age":23,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"HLA","Department":"Crm","Head":{"Id":5,"Name":"Sumita Nath"}},{"firstName":"Pogo","lastName":"Laal","Age":23,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"Designer"},{"firstName":"Sabina","lastName":"Sekh","Age":28,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"HLA Head","Department":"Crm"},{"firstName":"Sanjay","lastName":"Poudal","Age":24,"Company":"Switchme","Role":"HLA Head","Department":"Crm","Head":{"Id":10,"Name":"Sabina Sekh"}}];

const filtered = employee.filter(e => e.Age > 23 && e.Age < 27).map(e => `${e.firstName} ${e.lastName}`);

$("div.age").text(filtered.join(", "));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>4. List out all employee whose age&gt;23 and age&lt;27 ( comma separated)</h3>
<div class="age"></div>
```

I've filtered out the required employees, mapped them to the required strings and then put them in the `div` by joining.

Also, the reason for your current code not working is that you're not caring for what the previous value of `div.age` was, you're just overwriting it every time.